# Send excelsheet as response

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007

I have created excel sheet and saved using

```
xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs("abc.xls");
```

then I am using

```
 byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("abc.xls");
 File.Delete("abc.xls");
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.xls");
 Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
 Response.End();
```

to send the Excel sheet as response.

But the problem is on client side it is first prompting to save excel workbook "Book1" then it is prompting to save "abc.xls". How to prevent that?

Earlier I was using

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("abc.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

and it was working fine (directly prompting to save "abc.xls"). But I changed to  `xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs()` because the `xlWorkBook.SaveAs()` was throwing exception when deployed in IIS

Comment: _because the `xlWorkBook.SaveAs()` was throwing exception when deployed in IIS_ : didn't you try to fix that exception first? Seems to be related to access rights or something like this...

Comment: @Yannick Blondeau, if the problem caused by access rights, what about .SaveCopyAs method with the same path?:)
Sure, exception should be fixed rather than looking for workaround.

Comment: Earlier I deployed it in windows server 2003 R2 - IIS 6.0 it worked there fine. Now I am deploying it in  windows server 2008 R2 - IIS 7.0 and I am facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have my code

```
    string fileName = "xyz.xls";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";           

    /*      
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            //extract
        }
    }
    */


    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Also I have 
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
in my code.Also Try with it instead of application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: I tried changing the code as you have told but it is not working :(

Comment: have edited the code.
You just need to do changes of 
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray); inplace of Response.Write of my commented code.

May be problem with flush or clearing of header on your side